# Feature request: edit bounty message

Tags: feature-request

I just put up a [bounty](https://askubuntu.com/q/639999/814) message formatted in a way assuming paragraphs and bullet points are supported. Found out the hard way that it doesn't; is there a way to edit?

---

**EDIT**
Since it ain't possible, please consider this a [feature-request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/feature-request). And in the mean time, at least mention on the bounty message form that it can't be edited or something.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-custom-message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no method for editing bounty text. Once it is set it's stuck there. Sorry.

Comment: Well, [tag:feature-request] to the rescue?